# TikZ datavisualization unable to read from file

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-datavisualization

I am new to Tikz and hoping to use it's data visualization package, but the following simple test document fails to build;

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \datavisualization [scientific axes, visualize as scatter]
    data [ read from file = kuboout18117.csv ];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

with error;

```
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgf/data/read from file'
and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

Upon looking into documentation and existing posts, I am puzzled as to why this is happening!

The first few lines of the imported file are;

```
N , Gamma
2 , -0.00646673
3 , -0.00111146
4 , -3.1868e-05
5 , 0.000311116
6 , 0.000698315
```

which I thought seemed harmless enough.. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: is there any important reason you don't use the [`pgfplots` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots), which would make this much easier while at the same time offering far more options?

Comment: @Timm since I have been impressed with TikZ upon my reading of it, I thought it would be nice to be able to use the Datavisualization side of it. However upon looking into it further, as you say, I could well be better off with the `pgfplots` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I rewrote your example to make it work in `pgfplots` and tried to set some basic settings, however I'd recommend you to study some examples as well as the [pgfplots manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf).

The resulting LaTeX code four your plot would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{kuboout18117.csv}
N, Gamma
2, -0.00646673
3, -0.00111146
4, -3.1868e-05
5, 0.000311116
6, 0.000698315
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[
        scaled y ticks=false,
        y tick label style={
            /pgf/number format/fixed,
            /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
            /pgf/number format/precision=3,
            },
        ymin=-0.008, ymax=0.002,
        xmin=0, xmax=8,
        ]
        \addplot[only marks, mark=*] table[x=N, y=Gamma, col sep=comma] {kuboout18117.csv};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

with the visual result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that, I did have a play around yesterday with `pgfplots` and got some pleasing results, just need to tidy it up, but it does seem I can safely forget about `TikZ Datavisualisation`.